# How to use properties class object in child class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created a class 'a' with in package name 'pack1'

```
@Beforetest

public class a {

public properties prop;

public propLoad(){
Webdriver driver= new firefoxdriver();

 prop = new properties();
prop.load(driver);
}
```

also i have created a new package 'pack2' and new class 'b' and i want to use the prop object in b class

i have written the code as

```
@Test

public class b extends a{

prop.getproperties(keyname);
}
```

(Keys and values are defined in .properties file)

But when i have ran the code system gives me null pointer exception 
    Pls help me in this issue

Comment: What language is this? What framework is this? Assuming Java + TestNG, the `@Beforetest` annotation should be on the method `propLoad()` not the class.

Answer (score 0):

Define  `prop = new properties();` at class level

@Beforetest

```
public class a {

public properties prop=new properties();

public propLoad(){
Webdriver driver= new firefoxdriver();


prop.load(driver);
}
```

I am not sure for what reason you need to pass driver object here?   `prop.load(driver);` Anyways, instantiating prop class object at class level should do a trick. Let me know.